# DoctrineProxies should be compatible with Entity

Tags: laravel-4, doctrine-orm, entity

I have edited some methods in my Doctrine models to use TypeHinting. After adding TypeHinting in the models, I can't use them anymore. I am getting this error:

`ErrorException
Declaration of DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Entities\Place::setLocation() should be compatible with Entities\Place::setLocation(Entities\Location $location)`

I personally prefer to use TypeHinting, so I hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Have you recreated your proxies?

Comment: Anybody fancy explaining what this means in an answer? Bit of a dead-end and I'm having the same problem.